# Show entries that are parents of two specific children

Tags: playa

I'm trying to generate a list of entries that share two specific, common children. I have the entry_id's of the children, but Playa's template tags don't seem to have a way to display parents that share the same children. I found the plugin "Multiplaya" (https://github.com/croxton/Multiplaya) that seemed to fit the bill but it did not work for me.

The following gives me a list of parents of entry_id "26" **OR** "39", whereas I need parents of entry_ids "26" **AND** "39":

```
{exp:playa:parents entry_id="26|39" orderby="title" sort="asc"}
...    
{/exp:playa:parents}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [co-parent tag](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/coparents.html). Here's the code for your specific case:

```
{exp:playa:coparents child_id="26|39" orderby="title" sort="asc"}
    ...
{/exp:playa:coparents}
```

Comment: That's what I had thought would work, but in this particular case it does not. I have two Playa fields in this channel, but one is in a Matrix column and the other is a regular channel field. I wonder if that is causing the coparent tag to not work for me.

Comment: It shouldn't. If still is giving you trouble, feel free to shoot an email to support@pixelandtonic.com, though - we'll see what we can do.